# JavaScript Validation of a-z only

Tags: javascript

My encoder is printing -31 instead of "99"  I want to output to be 
8 5 12 12 15 0 23 15 18 12 4 99 for the input Hello World!

```
function fnEncode() {
  var msg = $("textin").value.toUpperCase();
  $("textin").value = msg;
  var outstr = "";
  var allowed = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

  for (var i=0; i<msg.length; i++) {
   if (msg[i] === " ") outstr += "0" + " ";
   else if (isChar(i) === isChar(allowed)) outstr+="99";
   else var c = msg.charCodeAt(i)-64+" ";
   // var x = msg.charAt(i) + " ";
   outstr+=c;
  }

  $("textout").value = outstr;
}

function isChar(str) {
  return /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(str);
}
```

Comment: Your browser's debugger and the `console.log()` function are your friends here; use them to figure out how these bits of code run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are running into a couple of issues, one with the way you are comparing the regex and one with code on subsequent lines not executing with your if statements

Consider using { & } for if statements to make things easier

the following code, executed in the console works seems to have the output you desire,

```
var msg = "Hello World!";
var allowed = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var outstr = "";
for (var i=0; i<msg.length; i++) {
   if (msg[i] === " ") {
        outstr+="0 ";
   } else if (!/^[a-zA-Z]$/.test(msg[i])) {
        outstr+="99";
   } else {
        var c = msg.charCodeAt(i)-64+" ";
        outstr+=c;
   }

 }

console.log(outstr);

8 37 44 44 47 0 23 47 50 44 36 99
```

I've kept my code as similar to your as possible, but you really should also look the answer from @phihag for getting ASCII codes from strings

Answer (score 1):

After an `if` or `else`, only the next instruction is executed. Use curly braces to have multiple instructions in a case, and proper indentation for human readers.

In addition, `charCodeAt` will give you the ASCII code (or Unicode codepoint for non-BMP characters), but that's not helpful. You want the 
 [index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) in `allowed` instead ([live demo](https://repl.it/@phihag/soencoding49157719)):

```
for (var i=0; i<msg.length; i++) {
    if (msg[i] === " ") {
        outstr += "0"+" ";
    } else {
        var idx = allowed.indexOf(msg[i].toUpperCase()); // -1 if not in allowed
        outstr += (idx < 0) ? "99" : (idx + 1);
        outstr += " "; 
    }
}
```